# Is it possible in the "Function.apply" method to get the index of the current item in the List?

Tags: java, transform, guava

I am trying to apply "transform" to `List <Map <String, String>>`. Is it possible in the "`Function.apply`" method to get the index of the current item in the List?

```
Lists.transform(data, new Function<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>() {
        private static int index = 0;

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> apply(Map<String, String> from) {
            from.put(key, value); // need to get index
            return from;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don't rollback my changes, I'm barely improving formatting.

Comment: What are `key` and `value` here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Often in Java, using a loop is much simpler and cleaner.

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = ...
for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    // i is the index.
    data.get(i).put(key, value);
}
```

I should say that I am in favour of functional programming in a language which supports it.  Java 7 is not well suited for functional programming and sometimes you have to resort to iteration. Java 8 and 9 promises to be more functional programming friendly with the addition of closures.

IMHO Java doesn't even support recursion as well as many languages do. A lack of [tail call elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in the JVM is a deficiency.

Comment: +1 The Guava programmers warn about using the [functional style too much](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) in Java ("Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code.")

Answer (score 0):

If your `Function.apply` is designed to return a `Map`, how could you change the method signature dynamically ?  Try to be as simple as possible if there is no need to do an Einstien. You may consider using loops as Mr.Peter has suggested. Also I feel that your code will not compile because your method returns a Map and you are actually returning  a string.